# Is QT Quick/QML capable of loading user defined plugins?

Tags: c++, qt, plugins, qml

I'm considering to build a QT Quick application that supports user/community defined plugins. Those plugins should be able to extend the existing UI, e.g. with custom windows or dialogs.

With the rather old QT widgets this would be no problem, since you can define a complete UI structure with C++ code which can be dynamically loaded at runtime.

However, QT Quick heavily relies on QML to create the UI. Doing this with C++ only is

1. quite complicated
2. highly discouraged by the QT docs

So what are my options to dynamically load user plugins into my existing QML UI at runtime? Is it even possible?

Comment: There are tons of ways to [load](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-loader.html) QML objects dynamically in QML.

Comment: It depends on your core design and what you want to achieve. You can make C++ plugins that embeds some QML resources and with your plugin API give the path of what to load. You can directly add QML files in some specified directory and parse them as files in your core app to load them. You can expose a model of windows/dialogs to display in a menu in which the plugin would add its own QML items.